# Can we use jquery freeze function in jqgrid's older version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using older version of jqgrid but frozen functionality is not available in older version, so i use some like this

```
jQuery(this).freezeColumns(2);
```

and it freezes column but the problem is when i click on checkbox of row in order to perform any action to get checked row count using jqgrid function

```
jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

it does not take checked count, 
is it happening because of freeze, can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use frozenColumn in old jqGrid 3.x when you get the module from the newest Guriddo jqGrid

Comment: Yes Tony you are right,that is why i used jquery freeze function,not the jqgrid function, but the problem is it does not take any count of row when clicked on check box, like i mention in my question.

Comment: I have not tested this freezeColumns, but maybe it will work only in common situations, but not in multiselect  and other features of the grid.

Comment: Hi Tony , any other way to freeze column in older version?